# Accessing elements in mxml from action script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml, flex-spark

I have a mxml application as below . How do I change text of label from actionscript file ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="initApp()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function initApp(){
                var p = new my_player("a");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Label x="700" y="409" text="Label" id="lble" width="131" height="41"/>
</s:Application>
```

my_player.as  code

```
package 
{
    import spark.components.Label;
    public class my_player
    {
        public var lble:Label;
        public function my_player(a:String)
        {
            lble.text="hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code breaks the basic principle of OOP - encapsulation. Or that I do not understand the problem.

Comment: @IlyaZ how come it breaks the encapsulation principles?

Comment: You have two Application instances there, which doesn't make much sense. If it is separating ActionScript from MXML your after, you should do some research on the Flex 4 (Spark) skinning architecture.

Comment: Please take a look at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_6.html before you continue with this mxml and as3 separation.

Comment: @Jari p object (first class) want link to label and change label in main application (second class) -> generation of new relations that make difficult the modification code in the future, it is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Inject label from main app to convey_player with constructor (another way - binding)

```
public function initApp(){
    var p = new my_player("a", lble);
}
```

---

```
public function my_player (a:String, targetLabel:Label)
{
    lble = targetLabel;
    lble.text="hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the second class :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    creationComplete="initApp()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        public function initApp(){

            // access your components by id
            lble.text  = "My new text for the label"
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Label x="700" y="409" text="Label" id="lble" width="131" height="41"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I have 4 type of streaming , each have seperate class as each has lot of code making it all in one mxml file isnt possible for me.

Comment: I am afraid you are using the wrong approach... I see no OOP in your implementation. Please consider giving a better example or a better explanation on what you want to achieve and not how to fix a particular issue you have